# Dependencie Injection struggle

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I hope I manage to explain this in a comprehensiv way:
Lets say we have a "library" object. In this "library", we have many "book" objects, and each "book" object has an "author" object.
Something like this:

```
class library {

  private $books = [];

  public function addBook( book $book){
    $this->books[]=$book;  
  }

  function getAllBookTitles(){
    foreach($this->books as $book)
      $r[] = $book->getTitle();
    return $r;
  }

}


class book {

  private $author;
  private $title;

  public function __construct( author $author ){
    $this->author = $author;
  }

  function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
  }

  function setTitle( $title ){
    $this->title = $title;
  }

}


class author {

  public function __construct(){}

}
```

Now what I don't really understand:
When, in some view, I only need the list of all the book titles of a library, why bother building the author objects ?
This is just an example, but image the "author" object was rather expensive to build ... This will then use a lot of resources for data that is not needed.

I understand that you could inject the "author" by a setter method to make it optional, but I want to use a factory to build the 'book' objects.

So in the end, what is the best way to tell your factory ( or repository ) what optional dependencies it should build the object with ?

Maybe my approach here is completely wrong, and my question doesn't make a lot of sense. If so, I apologise.
Any help to get me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to find a good artical about `Lazy loading objects and dependency injection` so that `dependencys` will only created when they are really needed.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I am however a bit surprised; when seraching for lazy loading and dependeny injection, there is not a ton of results. Isn't this a topic everyone should be interested in ? Or is this so common practice, and my lack of understanding is to blame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *lazy lifestyle* for your `author` dependency.  Instead of injecting an `author` object into your `book` constructor, you'd inject an `authorFactory`.  `authorFactory` is cheap to create, and is able to create `author` objects on demand.  You'd probably also need to add an `authorId` to the `book` constructor so that you know which author to create when necessary.  Then if/when your `book` object needs to use its `author` property, it does

```
if ($this->author == null)
{
   $this->author = $this->authorFactory->createAuthor($this->authorId)
}
// Do the rest of your method
```

You can also do this using closures rather than a class factory.

In your example, I'm assuming that you're doing something like showing a list of books along with the author's name, and then you show the author's entire details if the user clicks on the book's author.  So in that situation, you probably only need the author's name most of the time, in which case you can make the author's name a property of `book` and that'll be cheap to create.  Then if the user clicks on the book's author, you perform your lazy loading.

Another advantage of this method is that you may want to perform some sort of author caching so you're not hitting your database every time if the same author is clicked on several times.  You can do that caching inside your `authorFactory` and make it invisible to `book`.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Inject the factory class to lazy load.... of course !

Comment: Two mini follow-up questions:
1) What would you recommend ? Closures or factory injection ? Is there any difference ?
2) What about "$this->authorFactory.createAuthor($this->authorId)" ? I have never seen this notation with a point. Is that a typo or valid syntax ?

Comment: 1) Personally, I would use a factory because I think that makes unit testing easier if you have a well defined factory object whose only purpose is to create Author objects.  I think closures makes it a little more confusing when writing unit tests.  But that's just my preference, and it's probably because factories are what I'm used to.  2) Yes, that's a typo.  I'm primarily a C# programmer, so accidentally used that syntax.

Comment: Another point about factories vs. closures is that if you do want to do some caching or other logic inside of your dependency creation, a factory is better suited for that.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot !